# Accessing BoundField Value Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

In GridView

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="DispatchQuantity" HeaderText="Dispatch Quantity" ItemStyle-CssClass="clsQty"/>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clsQty').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

This iterates correctly but without giving the value in the field(Just blank alerts without a value). How can i access values in BoundFields using Jquery?

Comment: Check how the `BoundField` element rendered in `DOM` and get the value according to that. If the value rendered as `InnerHTML` then user `$(this).html()` instead

Comment: Shevil answer is right! Or you can replace BoundField with TemplateField

Comment: Yes, Shevil is right: you must check how the element is rendered in DOM and you will find the solution. Maybe you will end doing something like that... $(this).children().val();

Comment: @Muhammed Shevil, Yes that worked. Thanks a lot!